# Options to improve conversion raster to polygon?

Tags: raster, r, polygon, convert

Is there a way to convert a `raster.tif` into a single polygon?

```r
# Loading raster.tif
DEM <- raster ("C: /Users//raster.tif")
# We generate boundary of the raster
poly_DEM <- DEM> -Inf
polygon <- rasterToPolygons (poly_DEM, dissolve = TRUE)***
```

I have tried `rasterToPolygons` if it works, but for longer rasters it takes too long, I think it is because it has to dissolve many pixels.

In summary, I just want to extract the edge of a raster in a single polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with improving raster to polygon conversion but, rather a bit of lack of understanding in how this should be applied. Converting a raster to polygons is intended to convert integer rasters with clustered values (eg., landcover) to a vector geometry. You are trying to convert a floating point raster with no discrete spatial patterns. In effect, you are converting every unique cell in your raster to a polygon.

Here is a simple solution to what you are after. The process is to create a raster with a uniform value, based on a copy of your original raster, then just mask it. This will give you a raster with a single value representing the areas with values in the original raster. This can then be converted to polygon(s).

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", 
            package="raster"))
  r[r >= 200] <- NA
    plot(r)

e <- raster(extent(r), nrows = nrow(r), 
            ncols = ncol(r))
  e[] <- 1
    e <- mask(e, r)  
plot(e)

p <- rasterToPolygons(e, dissolve = TRUE)
  plot(p)
```